# 気に入られ - appreciate/fond

Tags: meaning, word-choice

In this sentence 何か気に入られてる、みたいなんだけど

Kiniira means to be fond of or being appreciative?

My translation is " why does it seem like he's being appriciated?"

But maybe the word fond of is more likely? I can't think of a grammatically correct way to construct a sentence with"fond"

Edit: the sentence is is being said by an observer that wonders about the relationship between two people.

Answer (score 2):

- (～を)[気【き】に入【い】る](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%B0%97%E3%81%AB%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8B): set phrase "to become fond of ～; to like ～"
- 気に入られる: the passive version of 気に入る. "I am liked"
- 気に入られている: the progressive version of 気に入られる "I am being liked"
- 気に入られてる: the [contracted version](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010) of 気に入られている

何か in this context is not "why" but "kinda" or "somehow". Please see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/25556/5010).

> 何か(彼に)気に入られてる、みたいなんだけど…
>   Looks like... I'm somehow liked (by him)...

Note that the implied subject of this sentence is probably "私" (i.e., 私**は**彼**に**気に入られている = **I** am liked **by** him).